# Nested UserProfile in User resource django tastypie

Tags: django, api, tastypie

I am using django tastypie and I'm trying to add a nested userprofile resource in my user resources:

My code:

Models (in APP_FOLDER/models.py):

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile')
```

Resource definitions (in API/resources.py):

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    userprofile = fields.ToManyField('api.resources.UserProfileResource', 'userprofile', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'

class UserProfileResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ToOneField(UserResource,'user')

    class Meta:
        queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'userprofile'
```

When I try to access the users I get: error_message: "'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'all'". Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out: I needed to change fields.ToManyField to fields.ToOneField in the UserResource since the relationship is one to one in the models.